# Is sending an audio file with a portion of an accession number a violation of HIPAA

Tags: hipaa, audio

Assuming a hypothetical scenario:

The hospital radiology dictation system is down. The transcriptionist works off-site. The radiologist has the ability to record an audio file on his phone or laptop computer and email this to the transcriptionist to be typed.

If the dictation via this manner uses the accession number and date of study to identify the study, but not patient name, MRN, date of birth, or other identifiers, my research suggests this may be a HIPAA violation.

If only a portion (say last 3 digits) of the 6 to 9 digit accession were used, would this be a violation? Using only a portion of the number would be enough so that the typed job could eventually be matched up with the appropriate study when the dictation system comes back up.